# Interating over all available Ant properties

Tags: java, loops, ant, properties, build

I'm running a long, complex Ant script. For debugging purposes, I'd like to to iterate over all available Ant properties (all that are set) and print their name and value.

Is there a way to get a hold of a list of Ant properties at a given execution point so I could iterate through them using a for or foreach?

I looked quite a bit but I haven't found anything on the subject...

Thank you!!
Eduardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print them, you can use [<echoproperties/>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html).